# Do wizards in Harry Potter's world wear trousers under their robes?

Tags: j-k-rowling, harry-potter

There has been lively discussion about whether or not witches and wizards in the world of Harry Potter wear trousers under their robes (for example, in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ohwitchplease/status/826658575296573441)). I have not yet seen a definitive answer to this question online, though I have seen theories thrown around based on certain passages or statements by Rowling (like [this one](https://twitter.com/AlanMattli/status/824931210518487040)).

**Is there any evidence in HP canon that wizards did/did not wear trousers under their robes?**

Comment: Related question on scifi: [In the HP books, what do wizards wear under their robes?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53815)

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? I think I know why, but I think that it would do us all good to get in the habit of explaining it.

Comment: @Benjamin There are a few theories floating around in [chat, now](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35418303#35418303). (I do agree that some comments would be nice...)

Comment: Yes, I am reading those, but not everyone checks there and it is also about the habit we should get into.

Comment: @Benjamin I have not voted either way (I don't think it is worth either), but this seems to me to be a joke question (or at least comically phrased) and some people might have issues with that on a literature site.

Comment: I know, @Benjamin, I know. I totally agree that people should write comments about a question they have a problem with in situ

Comment: @MatrimCauthon Thank you for the critique of the question. Can you help me understand what can be improved about the phrasing of the question, or (if you want to) [edit] it to improve it?

Comment: @Shokhet I am not sure exactly how... it is inherently a silly question. I would definitely edit the #Robegate out of the title. (I am not going to do that for you, that is not what the peer edits are for, as it is a style choice in the end)

Comment: @MatrimCauthon Okay, will do. Thank you for that advice

Comment: @amaranth I've never used SO. I've noticed that many people are reluctant to leave comments, but I will usually be receptive of respectful, constructive criticism.

Comment: @Shokhet: I think it's downvoted because you should have found the exactly duplicate question on Sci Fi SE easily, eg. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bharry-potter%5D+robe+under

Comment: @b_jonas Users of Literature SE aren't obligated to be members of SFF.SE, or even to know it exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about the workings of a fantasy world, not its literary depth or value. (Note: I am not downvoting it while the community make up their mind).

Comment: @MattThrower I disagree - by that logic we'd have to ban *all* questions about the "world of" a book, which I don't think that we should do. Also, this particular question can be directly answered from the text.

Comment: I'm going to be in favor of keeping the question open: I'm not sure what exactly "literary depth or value" means but here's a thought experiment for this question: imagine the op is a film director making the harry potter movies and wants to determine what costumes the actors should wear. Wouldn't that be a good use of this site?

Comment: @EJoshuaS A fair argument. I'll just repost what I said to the OP in chat. Essentially, that question seems to me to very clearly cross the line between where we end and Sci-Fi & Fantasy begins and would thus be far more at home in the latter. What I'm struggling with is why that seems to clear to me when it obviously doesn't for many other users.

Comment: In an effort to keep these two discussions together, the chat conversation mentioned by @MattThrower continues [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42149184#42149184).

Answer (score 17):

Since this is basically the same question as the one on Sci-Fi I will summarize the [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53815/in-the-hp-books-what-do-wizards-wear-under-their-robes) from @Valorum.

Basically, some wear underwear, some don't even go that far. Valorum gives more quotes (I encourage you to take a look at his answer), but I feel that these are the best examples.

From *The Order of the Phoenix*, here's an example with underwear:

> Snape was hanging upside-down in the air, his robes falling over his head to reveal skinny, pallid legs and **a pair of greying underpants**.

From *The Goblet of Fire*, an example without underwear:

> Harry, Ron and Hermione joined it, right behind a pair of men who were
>   having a heated argument. One of them was a very old wizard who was
>   wearing a long flowery nightgown. The other was clearly a Ministry
>   wizard; he was holding out a pair of pinstriped trousers and almost
>   crying with exasperation. ‘Just put them on, Archie, there’s a good
>   chap, you can’t walk around like that, the Muggle on the gate’s
>   already getting suspicious –’ ‘I bought this in a Muggle shop,’ said
>   the old wizard stubbornly. ‘Muggles wear them.’ ‘Muggle women wear
>   them, Archie, not the men, they wear these,’ said the Ministry wizard,
>   and he brandished the pinstriped trousers. ‘I’m not putting them on,’
>   said old Archie in indignation. ‘**I like a healthy breeze round my
>   privates, thanks.’**

All credit to Valorum for this, he did the work.

Comment: If people have a problem with me summarizing a different site's answer, let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: @MatrimCauthon if people have a problem, make it a community wiki.

Comment: @muru I agree, make it a community wiki. As "credit" measured on this site is rep, and if an answers is copied, the poster is  gaining rep on some else's work.

Comment: @Skooba I am going to keep it an answer, based on this [Meta](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/483/how-do-we-feel-about-using-other-peoples-answers-on-a-different-site-as-a-source) post

Comment: Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.... Granted you could have looked the quote for yourself and acheived the same result and not had to source the other answer to begin with.